# How to create a system restore point programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, backup, restore-points

I'm looking for a way to create a system restore point with the current date and time by pressing a button. I've tried searching the web for a simple way to do this but I haven't found one yet.

I found this code snippet from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but it is in VB and not C#, I tried converting it a bit but I don't think i'm doing a great job of translating it.

```
'CreateRestorePoint Method of the SystemRestore Class
'Creates a restore point. Specifies the beginning and 
'the ending of a set of changes so that System Restore 
'can create a restore point.This method is the 
'scriptable equivalent of the SRSetRestorePoint function.

Set Args = wscript.Arguments
If Args.Count() > 0 Then
    RpName = Args.item(0)
Else 
    RpName = "Vbscript"
End If

Set obj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!root/default:SystemRestore")

If (obj.CreateRestorePoint(RpName, 0, 100)) = 0 Then
wscript.Echo "Success"
Else 
    wscript.Echo "Failed"
End If
```

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845/creating-system-restore-points-thoughts

Answer (score 8):

Here's a VB.NET snippet to create a restore point (found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/49359/Programmatically-Create-System-Restore-Point)):

```
Dim restPoint = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:Systemrestore")
If restPoint IsNot Nothing Then
     If restPoint.CreateRestorePoint("test restore point", 0, 100) = 0 Then
         MsgBox("Restore Point created successfully")
    Else
         MsgBox("Could not create restore point!")
     End If
End If
```

Should be easy to "translate" to C#.

And here's another snippet in C# taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845/creating-system-restore-points-thoughts):

```
private void CreateRestorePoint(string description)
{
    ManagementScope oScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\default");
    ManagementPath oPath = new ManagementPath("SystemRestore");
    ObjectGetOptions oGetOp = new ObjectGetOptions();
    ManagementClass oProcess = new ManagementClass(oScope, oPath, oGetOp);

    ManagementBaseObject oInParams =
         oProcess.GetMethodParameters("CreateRestorePoint");
    oInParams["Description"] = description;
    oInParams["RestorePointType"] = 12; // MODIFY_SETTINGS
    oInParams["EventType"] = 100;

    ManagementBaseObject oOutParams =
         oProcess.InvokeMethod("CreateRestorePoint", oInParams, null); 
}
```

Comment: question is asked to be answered using c#. good answer anyway.

Comment: I tried that one previous @M4N, it gives me a bunch of missing assembly reference errors. I'm not sure which ones I need to add.

Comment: @Boundinashes6: You will probably have to add a reference to System.Management (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.aspx)

Comment: this doesn't not creating any restore point, still executes successfully. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5):

Late, but I improved the answer from M4N...

```
/// <summary>
///     The type of event. For more information, see <see cref="CreateRestorePoint"/>.
/// </summary>
public enum EventType
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     A system change has begun. A subsequent nested call does not create a new restore
    ///     point.
    ///     <para>
    ///         Subsequent calls must use <see cref="EventType.EndNestedSystemChange"/>, not
    ///         <see cref="EventType.EndSystemChange"/>.
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    BeginNestedSystemChange = 0x66,

    /// <summary>
    ///     A system change has begun.
    /// </summary>
    BeginSystemChange = 0x64,

    /// <summary>
    ///     A system change has ended.
    /// </summary>
    EndNestedSystemChange = 0x67,

    /// <summary>
    ///     A system change has ended.
    /// </summary>
    EndSystemChange = 0x65
}

/// <summary>
///     The type of restore point. For more information, see <see cref="CreateRestorePoint"/>.
/// </summary>
public enum RestorePointType
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     An application has been installed.
    /// </summary>
    ApplicationInstall = 0x0,

    /// <summary>
    ///     An application has been uninstalled.
    /// </summary>
    ApplicationUninstall = 0x1,

    /// <summary>
    ///     An application needs to delete the restore point it created. For example, an
    ///     application would use this flag when a user cancels an installation. 
    /// </summary>
    CancelledOperation = 0xd,

    /// <summary>
    ///     A device driver has been installed.
    /// </summary>
    DeviceDriverInstall = 0xa,

    /// <summary>
    ///     An application has had features added or removed.
    /// </summary>
    ModifySettings = 0xc
}

/// <summary>
///     Creates a restore point on the local system.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="description">
///     The description to be displayed so the user can easily identify a restore point.
/// </param>
/// <param name="eventType">
///     The type of event.
/// </param>
/// <param name="restorePointType">
///     The type of restore point. 
/// </param>
/// <exception cref="ManagementException">
///     Access denied.
/// </exception>
public static void CreateRestorePoint(string description, EventType eventType, RestorePointType restorePointType)
{
    var mScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\default");
    var mPath = new ManagementPath("SystemRestore");
    var options = new ObjectGetOptions();
    using (var mClass = new ManagementClass(mScope, mPath, options))
    using (var parameters = mClass.GetMethodParameters("CreateRestorePoint"))
    {
        parameters["Description"] = description;
        parameters["EventType"] = (int)eventType;
        parameters["RestorePointType"] = (int)restorePointType;
        mClass.InvokeMethod("CreateRestorePoint", parameters, null);
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
CreateRestorePoint("Example Restore Point", EventType.BeginSystemChange, RestorePointType.ModifySettings);
```

Comment: please provide some explanation to get user understand code and how to use not just provide code only.

Comment: I thought it was self-explanatory because of internal code summaries. But I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var restPoint = GetObject(@"winmgmts:\\.\root\default:Systemrestore");
if(restPoint!=null)
{
    if(restPoint.CreateRestorePoint("", 0, 100) == 0)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @David Brabant, that is giving me an Unrecognized escape sequence error at this point

var restPoint = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:Systemrestore");

Comment: Answer is from youhannesdedope. Edited it to fix the escape problem.

Comment: ok that error is gone but now i'm receiving the following error: The name 'GetObject' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ydd1987, code only answers aren't generally helpful as they don't explain the point of the answer. Please expand a little.

Comment: @Boundinashes6 Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, and then use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:Systemrestore")`