# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException while trying to create a system restore point using C#

Tags: c#, wmi, windows-10-iot-enterprise

I'm using the following C# code from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749528/how-to-create-a-system-restore-point-programatically).

```
ManagementScope oScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\default");
ManagementPath oPath = new ManagementPath("SystemRestore");
ObjectGetOptions oGetOp = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementClass oProcess = new ManagementClass(oScope, oPath, oGetOp);

ManagementBaseObject oInParams =
     oProcess.GetMethodParameters("CreateRestorePoint");
oInParams["Description"] = "Setting restore point";
oInParams["RestorePointType"] = 12; // MODIFY_SETTINGS
oInParams["EventType"] = 100;

ManagementBaseObject oOutParams =
     oProcess.InvokeMethod("CreateRestorePoint", oInParams, null);
```

The error is coming from the line which declares `oOutParams`.

I've wrapped this line in a try catch, and printed out the error code which is -2147023838 which I cannot find in any list of COM error codes listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/com-error-codes) (assuming the printed error code should be converted to hex 2's complement -> 0x80070422).

Without catching the exception (so basically the exact code above), the stack trace is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)
   at WindowsUpdatesDev.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

With the try/catch wrapped around the line that declares oOutParams I print the stack trace which is:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)                                                                                                           
at WindowsUpdatesDev.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

There is no message for this second stack trace.

Comment: Do you have the complete stack trace?  Let's see it.

Comment: And the stack trace of the inner exception, if there is one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have added the stack trace that prints when running the code above, and also the stack trace for the inner try/catch.

Comment: Information on the error code is [here](https://windows-hexerror.linestarve.com/0x80070422): *The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.*

Answer (score 1):

Following steps [here](https://windowsreport.com/restore-point-windows-10/) (specifically, all of step one and step two by setting 'Protection' to 'On' for my C: drive) allows the code above to run without errors.

Comment: Thanks for this- I couldn't find a reason as to why I was getting a COMException when attempting to set a restore point, but it turns out my IT department had come in and changed the System Restore settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on my own experience here, and as Ed said in his answer:

Make sure that your system is configured to allow you to set a restore point.

You can do this by performing the following steps:

1. Click the Windows key
2. Type "Create a restore point" and open the application suggested
3. Under the "System Protection" tab, make sure the protection is "On" for at least one of your drives